# How to add more information to my "Post" request (Sinatra)

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want ask a user for more information once they click one of the mood buttons. Example: If a user clicks on "Very Happy", I would like to pop another input form asking: "Would you like to add more info as to why you feel this way?"

If a user says no then proceed to posting.

If a user fills in additional info. Modify the information being posted to the database which one now include info to be posted to the property :mood_reason.

Any help in achieving this would be awesome.

**My Current situation**

Currently when a user clicks one of my buttons in image below:

[image]

I send the post request directly to my database using the following code:

```
post '/mood' do
 params.merge!(user_id: session[:id])
 Mood.create(params)
 redirect '/dashboard'
end
```

My Html.erb input forms looks like this:

```
<div style="height:50px;"></div>

<div class="w3-display-container" style="height:50px;">
<form action = "/mood" method = "post">
<input class="w3-button w3-display-middle w3-black" 
style="width:200px;" type="submit" name="mood" value="Very Happy" />
</form>
</div>

<div class="w3-display-container" style="height:50px;">
<form action = "/mood" method = "post">
<input class="w3-button w3-display-middle w3-black" 
style="width:200px;" type="submit" name="mood" value="Happy" />
</form>
</div>

<div class="w3-display-container" style="height:50px;">
<form action = "/mood" method = "post">
<input class="w3-button w3-display-middle w3-black" 
style="width:200px;" type="submit" name="mood" value="Neutral" />
</form>
</div>

<div class="w3-display-container" style="height:50px;">
<form action = "/mood" method = "post">
<input class="w3-button w3-display-middle w3-black" 
style="width:200px;" type="submit" name="mood" value="Sad" />
</form>
</div>

<div class="w3-display-container" style="height:50px;">
<form action = "/mood" method = "post">
<input class="w3-button w3-display-middle w3-black" 
style="width:200px;" type="submit" name="mood" value="Very Sad" />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is non-trivial.  You need to handle the 'submit' event on the form, save the state that your committing, use Javascript to detect and save the addition of data through the button presses, then finally do the post request with all the data you've collected, probably best in a `data` Javascript object which includes the forms original data + the additional data added through your UI.